# Primes with Distinct Prime Digits

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

There are 18 primes with distinct prime digits ([A124674](https://oeis.org/A124674)). Namely, they are:

\$2, 3, 5, 7, 23, 37, 53, 73, 257, 523, 2357, 2753, 3257, 3527, 5237, 5273, 7253, 7523\$

Your task is to output this sequence.

## Rules

- [sequence](/questions/tagged/sequence) [rules](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/sequence/info) apply. This means valid solutions may use any of the following formats:

  - Given some index \$n\$ it can return the \$n\$-th entry of the list.
  - Given some index \$n\$ it can return all entries up to the \$n\$th one in the sequence.
  - Without taking any index, it can output *all* entries by e.g. ...

    - ...printing them one by one (potentially infinitely) or...
    - ...returning a list (lazy if the sequence is infinite) or...
    - ...returning a generator that represents the whole sequence.
    - Note: the solution may print/generate infinitely, but once the entire sequence is output, subsequent outputs must be blank.
- If taken, you may assume the input \$n\$ is always valid. (with 0-based indexing, \$ 0 \le n \le 17 \$; with 1-based indexing, \$ 1 \le n \le 18 \$)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf); fewest bytes wins.
- Standard loopholes apply.

Comment: Nice first challenge!

Comment: We only have 10 digits in the base10 system (actually, less because this asks for prime digits) . I'm wondering how this sequence is infinite...

Comment: @UndoneStudios it's not infinite - the challenge says there are only 18 numbers in the sequence. The phrase *"printing them one by one (potentially infinitely)"* means that the program doesn't have to halt after printing all of them.

Comment: *Potentially infinitely* confused me, my bad. Shouldn't that be changed?

Comment: @UndoneStudios It's like that because it's copied from the [tag:sequence] info page. However, I think it still applies, since my added note clarifies this issue

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
;DẒ;ŒQẠµ#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/a5eGuSdZHJwU@3LXg0Fbl//8NLQA)

Takes \$1 \le n \le 18\$ on STDIN and returns the first \$n\$

### How it works

```
;DẒ;ŒQẠµ# - Main link. Takes no arguments
       µ  - Previous chain as a monad f(k):
 D        -   Digits of k, D
;         -   Prepnd k
  Ẓ       -   Prime?
    ŒQ    -   Unique sieve; Cast k to digits, replace a digit with a 1 if it hasn't appeared before, else 0
   ;      -   Concatenate the two lists
      Ạ   -   All truthy?
        # - Read n from STDIN. Starting k=0, count up until n k's return true under f(k)
```

The way `ŒQ` works can be shown e.g. with \$k = 75523\$:

```
   [7, 5, 5, 2, 3]
ŒQ:[1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
```

It auto-casts \$k\$ to digits, then replaces all but the first occurence of each element with `0`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>12 11</s> 9 bytes

```
Þp~Þu'fæA
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnnB+w551J2bDpkEiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Prints the sequence infinitely.

Saved a byte by using a trick from caird's Jelly answer. 
Saved 2 bytes thanks to emanresu A.

##### Explanation

```
Þp~Þu'fæA
Þp         # All primes
  ~Þu      # Filtered by are their digits unique
     'fæA  # Filtered by are their digits all prime
```

Old:

```python
Þun:fpæA∧)l
         )l  # First n non-negative integers where:
Þu           #  It has unique digits
        ∧    #  And
  n:fp       #  Its digits with it prepended
      æA     #  All are prime
```

Comment: [9](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLDnnB+w551J2bDpkEiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14 11</s> 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
∞ʒÐÙQiDªpP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//Uce8U5MOTzg8MzDT5dCqgoD//wE)

Doesn't halt after printing all of them so you'll have to press the stop button.

*-1 thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

##### Explanation

```python
∞ʒ          # All positive integers filtered by:
  DÙQ       #  Digits are unique
     i      # And:
      Dª    #  Its digits with itself appended
        pP  #  Are all prime
```

Comment: You can combine the two filters with an if-statement for -1 byte: `∞ʒÐÙQiDªpP`. :)

Comment: [I've also posted an alternative 10-byter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258376/52210) that does finish. ;)

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + [bsdgames](https://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/BSD_games) + [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/), 40

```bash
primes 2 7777|egrep -v '[^2357]|(.).*\1'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoMze1WMFIwRwIalLTi1ILFHTLFNSj44yMTc1jazT0NPW0YgzV//8HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
lambda x:ord('%5Iāȋवુಹ෇ᑵᒙ᱕ᵣ'[x])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWUAmv9weXRob24z/2Y9XP9sYW1iZGEgeDpvcmQoJwIDBQcXJTVJxIHIi@CkteCrgeCyueC3h@GRteGSmeGxleG1oydbeF0p/2ZvciB4IGluIHJhbmdlKDAsMTgpOnByaW50KGYoeCkp/w)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 72 bytes

```
1¶11¶111¶4$*
+%1`1
2$'¶$`3$'¶$`5$'¶$`7
A`(.).*\1
.+
$*
A`^(11+)\1+$
%`1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@fy/DQNkMwBhImKlpc2qqGCYZcRirqh7apJBhDKFMIZc7lmKChp6mnFWPIpafNBVTsmBCnYWiorRljqK3CpZpg@P8/AA) Outputs all the terms of the sequence. Explanation:

```
1¶11¶111¶4$*
```

Insert 1, 2, 3, and 4 `1`s.

```
+%1`1
2$'¶$`3$'¶$`5$'¶$`7
```

Expand into all possible integers with up to 4 prime digits.

```
A`(.).*\1
```

Remove integers with duplicate digits.

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
A`^(11+)\1+$
```

Filter out composite numbers.

```
%`1
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 64 bytes

```
Select[FromDigits/@Join@@Permutations/@Subsets@{2,3,5,7},PrimeQ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277Pzg1JzW5JNqtKD/XJTM9s6RY38ErPzPPwSEgtSi3tASoLj8PKBZcmlScWlLsUG2kY6xjqmNeqxNQlJmbGhj7H0jnlSg4pP//DwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
Èì_â fjÃ¶X©j}jU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=yOxf4iBmasO2WKlqfWpV&input=MTg)

Outputs the first \$n\$ entries in the sequence.

Explanation:

```python
Èì_â fjÃ¶X©j}jU  # input stored in U
È           }jU  # get first U numbers where the following is true:
 ì_              # convert to digits
   â             #   keep unique digits
     fj          #   remove non-prime digits
       Ã¶X       # does this result in the same number?
          ©j     # and check the original is prime
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 59 bytes

```perl
(1x$_)!~/^(11+)\1+$/&/^[2357]+$/&!/(.).*\1/&&say for 2..1e4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/DsEIlXlOxTj9Ow9BQWzPGUFtFX00/LtrI2NQ8FsRW1NfQ09TTijHUV1MrTqxUSMsvUjDS0zNMNfn//19@QUlmfl7xf13fMlM9QwMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 213 bytes

```
-[----->+>+>+<<<]>-.---.>.<.>++.<.>++.<.>>-.+.<<.>>.<.<.>--.>.<<.>++.>.<<.>>-.<--.++.<.>--.>.+.<<.>>-.+.<.++.<.>>-.<.--.>+.<<.>>.-.<.++.<.>>+.<--.>-.<++.<.>--.>.+.<++.<.>--.>-.<++.>+.<<.>.>-.<--.>+.<<.>++.--.>-.+.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY1RCoBACEQPJHoC8SLRRwVBBH0End/G1W1pF1Zn3uiu93Jc@7Od7jxxHKO4qjobC7SYqBjReOGjRgOFkpnE2SChcDPeMHU/rG@NSsC@jAeiNh@J/46hEtWs1IclATJC4v4C)

Sets up 3 cells with ASCII 255/5=51 (character `3`) then produces the output hunt and peck style (with increments and decrements as necessary).

Cell 1 is used to print `2` and thereafter the separator `/`

Cell 2 is used to print `3` `5` `7` and thereafter the digits `5` & `7`

Cell 3 is used to print the digits `2` and `3`

It's possible that a 4th cell may lead to shorter code by allowing separate cells to be used for `5` and `7`. I may investigate this later.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₄ÅpʒÐÙSpÏQ
```

Outputs the entire sequence.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVPL4daCU5MOTzg8M7jgcH/g//8A)

Alternative 10-byter that I deemed different enough for its own answer. Make sure to upvote [*@TheThonnu*'s 10-bytes 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258303/52210) as well!

**Explanation:**

```python
₄           # Push 1000
 Åp         # Pop and push a list of the first 1000 prime numbers (up to 7919)
   ʒ        # Filter it by:
    Ð       #  Triplicate the prime number
     Ù      #  Pop one copy, and uniquify its digits
      Sp    #  Check for each unique digit whether it's a prime number
        Ï   #  Pop another copy, and only keep its digits at the truthy indices
         Q  #  Check if the two integers are still the same
            # (after which the filtered list is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 66 bytes

Prints the sequence and keeps looping forever.

```javascript
{for(n=x=2;;)n%--x||x>1|/(.).*\1|[^2357]/.test(x=n++)||print(n-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/vzotv0gjz7bC1sjaWjNPVVe3oqamws6wRl9DT1NPK8awJjrOyNjUPFZfryS1uESjwjZPW1uzpqagKDOvRCNP11Cz9v9/AA)

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 71 bytes

Prints the sequence and stops.

```javascript
{for(n=x=2;n<8e3;)n%--x||x>1|/(.).*\1|[^2357]/.test(x=n++)||print(n-1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFbCoAgEADA0wRaqKhEgtlFekBEQX1soSJC29lt5lrTGjZ/PpElU8p73J6Ay05Z6M2uLYWKsYyYB4mCcMrrSeK4KN12s@BxD5FkB01DER9/QiTAJP1K@QE)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>58 57</s> 55 bytes

```javascript
n=>'%5Iāȋवુಹ෇ᑵᒙ᱕ᵣ'.charCodeAt(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k6diZmVXVzV1PNI44nuB0u2Pljd@GDTzgfb2x9O3Ppw0syHG6c@3LpYXS85I7HIGajLsUQjT/O/NVdafpGCRqaCrYKBtUKmgo2CoQWQ1tbWVKhOzs8rzs9J1cvJT9dI08jU1Kz9DwA)

Port of Sisyphus's Python answer.

*-3 thanks to @Arnauld*

Comment: @Arnauld thanks, updated

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
¢\W░i*δÿ╛ñê╠≤▬J
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9b5c57b0692aeb98bea488ccf3164a&i=)

This is Packed Stax, which when unpacked represents the following 18 bytes

```
VIfEccu=^+_+{|pm|A
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=VIfEccu%3D%5E%2B_%2B%7B%7Cpm%7CA&i=)

```
VIf                # filter the following over infinity
   E cu=           # Are all the digits in the number unique?
    c   ^+         # Increment this and add it to the list (yielding prime value 2 for truthy)
          _+       # add the current value to the list
                |A # are all of the values in this list
            {|pm   # prime?
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
ＩΦ×φχ∧⬤”)∨∧i#”‹№ＩιＩμＩλ⬤…²ι﹪ιλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYsxCsMwDEWvIjLJ4ILltVMIdGohlF7AJKY1KDbYTq@vRoX8v7zhveUT6lICi8w15Y5TaB1viXus@EpbbEjOOQvkjIUxrzgy40DkPelpsHCPreFU9rNOh/mHzZzERlHTZ8jviN6CWo@y7lwwWVDh2FVELl/@AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
   φ                        Predefined variable `1000`
  ×                         Multiplied by
    χ                       Predefined variable `10`
 Φ                          Filtered where
       ”...”                Compressed string `1122121211`
      ⬤                     All characters satisfy
             №              Count of
                 μ          Inner index
                Ｉ           Cast to string
               ι            In outer value
              Ｉ             Cast to string
            ‹               Is less than
                   λ        Current character
                  Ｉ         Cast to integer
     ∧                      Logical And
                     …      Range from
                      ²     Literal integer `2`
                       ι    To current value
                    ⬤       All values satisfy
                         ι  Outer value
                        ﹪   Modulo (i.e. is not divisible by)
                          λ Inner value
Ｉ                           Cast to string
                            Implicitly print
```

34 bytes for a less inefficient version:

```
⊞υωＦυＦ⁺ι⁻⪪2357¹⪪ι¹⊞υκＩΦＩυ∧ι⬤…²ι﹪ιλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwEETvfsXS0wbiwYp46KkI3gpBvyC01S4uSUmy@vkxsTiXnZ1h3rjYMHrLORuJC4qGj@p2Dx8ARcHvGpaIpGEgV8x9ZUrYtMfTudFwUBq2hOpTBH/Oq3BMIJfwYmPCK3Gaw@alrHo31U3PjDfrnjO2Gqjkg5@Efa244lSXc96/@Qs) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υω
```

Start with the empty string.

```
Ｆυ
```

Loop over the strings of digits.

```
Ｆ⁺ι⁻⪪2357¹⪪ι¹
```

Append each prime digit that isn't yet present.

```
⊞υκ
```

Save the new strings to the list of numbers with distinct prime digits.

```
ＩΦＩυ∧ι⬤…²ι﹪ιλ
```

Output only those strings that represent primes.

33 bytes by using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO:

```
⊞υωＦ⁴«≔ΣＥ2357⁺κΦυ¬№μκυＩΦＩυ⬤…²κ﹪κμ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iOSOxKDk_MWfBgqWlJWm6FjdnBZQWZ2iU6iiUa1pzpeUXKWiYaCpUc3E6FhdnpudpBJfmavgmFmgoGRmbmivpKATklBZrZOsouGXmlKQWgfT55ZdoOOeX5pVo5OooZGuCgY5CKdA0zoCiTKCwc2JxiQZUPZhdCpR3zMnRCErMS0_VMALp0lHwzU8pzckHGZ0LNsKaq3ZJcVJyMdSdy6OVdMtylGKhXAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υω
```

Start with the empty string.

```
Ｆ⁴«
```

Loop `4` times.

```
≔ΣＥ2357⁺κΦυ¬№μκυ
```

For each prime digit, prefix it to all previous strings that do not already contain that digit, and concatenate all of the resulting lists.

```
ＩΦＩυ⬤…²κ﹪κμ
```

Output only those strings that represent primes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/),  <s>64</s>  45 bytes

```
[ "%5Iāȋवુಹ෇ᑵᒙ᱕ᵣ"nth ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AWMAnP9mYWN0b3L/VVNJTkc6IHNlcXVlbmNlcyBwcmV0dHlwcmludCA7CgoxOCBpb3Rh/1sgIgIDBQcXJTVJxIHIi@CkteCrgeCyueC3h@GRteGSmeGxleG1oyJudGggXf9tYXAgLv8)

-19 by porting Sisyphus' [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258332/97916).

Returns the nth number in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, 145 bytes

```
=LET(
    a,SEQUENCE(6^5),
    b,FILTER(a,MMULT(N(LEN(a)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(a,{2,3,5,7},""))=1),{1;1;1;1})=LEN(a)),
    FILTER(b,MMULT(N(MOD(b,TOROW(a))=0),a^0)=2)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), 288 bytes

Golfed version, [run it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1jsEKAjEMRH8lt02hLKiIh_0UkaUr7Rppm5LWk_jvthRlL3vJQDIzeU44ABUrhdlnoJBYCiQr4VVMIY5Zw_1hKFbhsFDsywlcC2az2tF4_8tRnpNQsBNUiQWvbQzD-GSKGEzCXERDUkqBY4EEFHv72OrmxmEWb3H7H3M35z3zlgvfRw0nDWcNl48G6VFpUTFxtXiot_ae3B8WdyHVTX0Bod1jNw==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

```
from itertools import permutations, chain, combinations; from sage.all import is_prime; print([int(''.join(map(str, p))) for p in chain.from_iterable(permutations(s) for s in chain.from_iterable(combinations({2, 3, 5, 7}, r) for r in range(1, 5))) if is_prime(int(''.join(map(str, p))))])
```

Ungolfed version, [run it online!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1kM1KBDEMgO-FvkNu22IZWEU8-SQiS0c7Y2SalqRzEt_dSbvKXjyVJvm-_CxcMmBL3ErZBDDXwg1q4ry32LCQBHj7iEjHU_KMNILWLApKXNMUt-2XQ7lUxpysseYdV2wCz_B1H-AhwGOAp29rZJ8l9XjXTuq56ABx3pK77eGGIQB7WAoDAxJwpDW5c4At0bXAwx2cvbdGp_5PfLuRkyEUFV7nOXDaO-2Qmjudps-C5HKsThoHqN4PqCrUO2lHXVahF-pJ0mT34PJ3DEf-VQ9yfA7zQPwPeBN-xg==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

```
from itertools import permutations, chain, combinations
from sage.all import is_prime

digits = {2, 3, 5, 7}
subsets = chain.from_iterable(combinations(digits, r) for r in range(1, len(digits) + 1))
perms = chain.from_iterable(permutations(s) for s in subsets)
nums = (int(''.join(map(str, p))) for p in perms)
primes = [n for n in nums if is_prime(n)]

print(primes)
```